# 2D spatial index optimized for queries of multiple regions

Tags: data-structures, spatial-index

I have a search space of a large number of axis-aligned boxes. A normal spatial index, like an r-tree, will rapidly give me a list of boxes that overlap one search area.

However, I have a large number (hundreds) of potentially overlapping search areas I'd like to query all at once. In other words, I want all objects in my data structure that overlap at least one of these five hundred boxes.

Is there a data structure optimized for this kind of query?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a quadkey and a placeholder. You can create a quadkey by interleave the x-and y co-ordinate. It's use in a morton curve a.k.a z curve.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this helps beyond a normal range searching data structure?

Comment: You can use a placeholder in the key:Abcd*bbcc.

Comment: I'm still not sure I see how this would work - why would a placeholder help you do range searches over multiple overlapping ranges more efficiently than in other data structures?

Comment: Isn't a multiple overlapping query uses a placeholder?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with spatial structures, but I don't see why that would be the case. For example, how would you represent the query for the rectangles [1, 1] x [2, 2] and [2, 2] x [3, 3] as a placeholder query?